# search string for everything before a set of characters in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I'm looking for a way to search a string for everything before a set of characters in C#. For Example, if this is my string value:

This is is a test.... 12345

I want build a new string with all of the characters before "12345".
So my new string would equal "This is is a test.... "
Is there a way to do this?

I've found Regex examples where you can focus on one character but not a sequence of characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use a Regex:

```
 public string GetBitBefore(string text, string end) 
 {
      var index = text.IndexOf(end);
      if (index == -1) return text;

       return text.Substring(0, index);
 }
```

Comment: thanks everyone! This  answer works best for me but I'll the replies are great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lazy quantifier to match anything, followed by a lookahead:

```
var match = Regex.Match("This is is a test.... 12345", @".*?(?=\d{5})");
```

where:

- `.*?` lazily matches everything (up to the lookahead)
- `(?=`…`)` is a positive lookahead: the pattern must be matched, but is not included in the result
- `\d{5}` matches exactly five digits. I'm assuming this is your lookahead; you can replace it

Answer (score 1):

You can do so with help of regex lookahead.

```
 .*(?=12345)
```

Example:

```
var data = "This is is a test.... 12345";

var rxStr = ".*(?=12345)";

var rx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex (rxStr, 
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var match = rx.Match(data);
if (match.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine (match.Value);
}
```

Above code snippet will print every thing upto 12345:

```
 This is is a test....
```

For more detail about see regex [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
var reg = new Regex("^(.+)12345$");
var match = reg.Match("This is is a test.... 12345");
var group = match.Groups[1]; // This is is a test....
```

Of course you'd want to do some additional validation, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: im gueassing ´\d.´ is a better regex rule than 12345 or else he could just split on 12345 and take index 0 or the result.

Comment: @ThomasAndreèLian -- he indicated he has a known set of characters... for example 12345.  Not necessarily all decimal, just a known value.

Answer (score 0):

You could just split, not as optimal as the indexOf solution

```
string value = "oiasjdoiasj12345";
string end = "12345";
string result = value.Split(new string[] { end }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0] //Take first part of the result, not the quickest but fairly simple
```

Answer (score 0):

^ means start of string

$ means end of string

The asterisk tells the engine to attempt to match the preceding token zero or more times. The plus tells the engine to attempt to match the preceding token once or more

{min,max} indicate the minimum/maximum number of matches.

\d matches a single character that is a digit, \w matches a "word character" (alphanumeric characters plus underscore), and \s matches a whitespace character (includes tabs and line breaks).

[^a] means not so exclude a

The dot matches a single character, except line break characters

In your case there many way to accomplish the task.

Eg excluding digit: `^[^\d]*`

If you know the set of characters and they are not only digit, don't use regex but `IndexOf()`. If you know the separator between first and second part as "..." you can use `Split()`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this snippet:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "This is is a test.... 12345";

        // Here we call Regex.Match.
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<MySentence>(\w+\s*)*)(?<MyNumberPart>\d*)");


        foreach (Match item in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Groups["MySentence"]);
            Console.WriteLine("******");
            Console.WriteLine(item.Groups["MyNumberPart"]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```